# Swift 2.2 and NSProxy. How can I use it?

Tags: swift

The interface of NSProxy is

```
public class NSProxy : NSObjectProtocol {
    public class func alloc() -> Self
    public class func `class`() -> AnyClass
    public func forwardInvocation(invocation: NSInvocation)
    public func dealloc()
    public func finalize()
    public var description: String { get }
    public var debugDescription: String { get }
    public class func respondsToSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> Bool
}
```

so it doesn't have any initializers. But Swift compiler require to call `Super.init` from initializer of subclass.

> Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

```
class SimpleDecorator: NSProxy {
    let phone: Phone
    init(phone: Phone) { // compile error with Super.init
        self.phone = phone
    }
}
```

I don’t put it in the call to super, it won’t compile, but of course since NSProxy doesn’t have an init, it won’t compile when I call super.init().

Is it possible to have a subclass of NSProxy in Swift ?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: http://www.openradar.me/18548454.

Comment: _DateOriginated:04-Oct-2014 03:58PM_  maybe Apple fixed it.I tried to add initializer to NSProxy by extension, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

NSProxy is a abstract class. Apple docs about NSProxy says "An abstract superclass defining an API for objects that act as stand-ins for other objects or for objects that don’t exist yet".

The docs about abstract class of wikipedia says:

> In a language that supports inheritance, an abstract class, or
>   abstract base class (ABC), is a class that cannot be instantiated
>   because it is either labeled as abstract or it simply specifies
>   abstract methods (or virtual methods).

---

Calling super.init() for abstract class is wrong.