# Use NSProxy in Swift

Tags: swift, proxy-pattern, nsproxy

How to create an `NSProxy` subclass in Swift?

Trying to add any of the `init` methods fails with error:
"Super init can't be called outside of the initializer", or
"Super init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer"

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

Using Objective-C subclass as a Base class works, but feels more like a hack:

```
// Create a base class to use instead of `NSProxy`
@interface WorkingProxyBaseClass : NSProxy
- (instancetype)init;
@end

@implementation WorkingProxyBaseClass
- (instancetype)init
{
  if (self) {

  }
  return self;
}
@end



// Use the newly created Base class to inherit from in Swift
import Foundation

class TestProxy: WorkingProxyBaseClass {
  override init() {
    super.init()
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478679/swift-2-2-and-nsproxy-how-can-i-use-it

Comment: @MartinR it looks like an old question, I wonder, has anything changed.

Comment: Apparently not ..,

Comment: It is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1715.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the mention. I found a couple of workarounds and might post them here soon.

Comment: I guess most developer don't understand NSProxy or aren't even aware of it's existence. Still I think this should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: make Objective-C class that inherits from NSProxy and then inherit Swift class from it.

Example at my GitHub: https://gist.github.com/SoundBlaster/0e53bae4ab814537c5868564d95eb553

```objectivec
// Objective-C Header BaseProxyForSwift.h

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

NS_SWIFT_NAME(BaseProxyForSwift)
@interface BaseProxyForSwift : NSProxy

+ (id)with:(id)object;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```objectivec
// Objective-C Implementation BaseProxyForSwift.m

#import "BaseProxyForSwift.h"

@interface BaseProxyForSwift ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) id object;
@end

@implementation BaseProxyForSwift

+ (id)with:(id)object {
    BaseProxyForSwift *res = [self alloc];
    res.object = object;
    return res;
}

@end
```

```swift
// Swift Implementation BaseSwiftProxy.swift

import Foundation

public class BaseSwiftProxy: BaseProxyForSwift {}
```

```swift
// Usage in Swift

let a = NSObject()
let p = BaseSwiftProxy.with(a)
```

Don't forget about Objective-C Bridging Headers if you will mix languages in one project: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-objective-c-into-swift.

Comment: I think, this is what I've done back then.

Answer (score -1):

NSProxy is a abstract class. Apple docs about NSProxy says "An abstract superclass defining an API for objects that act as stand-ins for other objects or for objects that don’t exist yet".

The docs about abstract class of wikipedia says:

> In a language that supports inheritance, an abstract class, or abstract base class (ABC), is a class that cannot be instantiated because it is either labeled as abstract or it simply specifies abstract methods (or virtual methods).

`Calling super.init()` for abstract class is wrong. 
In second class you are not calling `super.init()` for abstract class but of `WorkingProxyBaseClass` which is a concrete class. In Objective c you have not called `[super init]` hence code is working.

Comment: The question is still open. How to instantiate an `NSProxy` subclass in Swift?